# How to cancel UIPageControl's UIControlEventValueChanged event?

Tags: ios, uipagecontrol

I have a page control, and I want to be able to prevent some page change events (without disabling the control entirely). Basically, I want the user to not be able to move to the next page until they've answered all the questions on the current page, but I still want them to be able to move backwards.

Is there any way to have the control listen to something like a "will change" event and cancel it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this, where `condition` is a BOOL that you would set to yes if they've answered all the questions,

```
@implementation ViewController {
    BOOL condition;
    NSInteger pageNumber;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    pageNumber = 5; // I set this to 5 which was the page control's inital value just for the test
    condition = NO;
}



- (IBAction)pageControlTapped:(UIPageControl *)sender {
    if (condition) {
         pageNumber = sender.currentPage;
        // move to the next or previous page
    }else{
        if (pageNumber >= sender.currentPage) {
            pageNumber = sender.currentPage;
            // move to the previous page
        }else{
            sender.currentPage = pageNumber;
            // don't move
        }
    }
}
```